# Why is the sum of eigenvalues of a PCA equal to the original variance of the data?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra

Can someone please give or point to a proof? Can't seem to find a post that address this directly.

Comment: What constitutes a "proof" will depend on what you want to assume known about linear algebra and PCA, so you might want to give some indication of that. Because the sum of eigenvalues is the trace and the trace is invariant under conjugation, *QED*.

Comment: This appears to be a [tag:self-study] question.  If that is the case, please read our [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and tag your question as well.

Comment: @Tavrock You may be right, who knows, but I tend to think that it is the question of someone trying to understand PCA conceptually.

Comment: I think that the idea is that there is no need for a proof in the classical sense of induction, or contradiction, etc. It all stems from the definition of the covariance matrix of a dataset and its properties.

Answer (score 5):

1. **PCA rests on the singular value decomposition of the covariance matrix ($\text{Cov}(\text{Data})$):**

The covariance matrix is a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), and all Gramian matrices can be expressed as $A^\top A$. $A^\top A$ matrices have wonderful properties:

> 1. Symmetry
> 2. Positive semidefinite-*ness*
> 3. Real and positive eigenvalues
> 4. The trace is positive (the trace is the sum of eigenvalues)
> 5. The determinant is positive (the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues)
> 6. The diagonal entries are all positive
> 7. Orthogonal eigenvectors
> 8. Diagonalizable as $Q\Lambda Q^T$
> 9. It is [possible to obtain a Cholesky decomposition](https://mathoverflow.net/q/155147/74150).
> 10. Rank of $A^TA$ is the same as rank of $A$.
> 11. $\text{ker}(A^TA)=\text{ker}(A)$

2. **The trace is the sum of variance values in the diagonal of $\text{Cov}(\text{data})=A^\top A$.**

This is just the structure of the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Definition) with the elements

$$E[(X_i-\mu_i)(X_i-\mu_i)]$$

along the diagonal.

3. [**The trace is the sum of eigenvalues**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/546167/152225).

---

Scrappy proof in R:

```
> set.seed(0)                         # To replicate results
> data = matrix(rnorm(50), nrow = 10) # Made-up toy matrix 10 x 5
> covariance = cov(data)              # Covariance of the data matrix
> SVD_d = svd(covariance)$d           # Eigenvalues of the covariance matrix
> sum(diag(covariance))               # Trace of the covariance matrix:
[1] 4.242387
> sum(SVD_d)                          # Sum of eigenvalues:
[1] 4.242387
```

Comment: I think the sum of eigenvalues of PCA is equal to the sum of variance of the data only when the PCA is performed on the empirical sample covariance matrix $X^TX/n$. When the PCA is applied to the data matrix $X^TX$ this relationship no longer hold since the constant of proportionality $n$ (the sample size) is needed.

Comment: @Confounded Thank you for pointing this out. Feel free to edit the post if you feel it could improve it.